# "Element not found" issue occurred from time to time

Tags: pycharm, robotframework

I have written a code and it has 4 areas and my code is a little bit longer. When I compile all 4 areas within one attempt, sometimes the code is working properly, but sometimes not and it is shown below error;

> Element with locator ‘xpath=//input[@id=‘submit3’]’ not found.

This is the code part that related to my question,

```
    click element  xpath://html/body/app-root/div[1]/app-sidebar/div/ul/li[5]/a/p
    sleep  10s
   
    input text   ${LOCATOR_Card_Number}     ${Card_Number}
    Sleep  1s
    input text   ${LOCATOR_code}    ${code}
    
    IF    ${Card_Number} != 111111
            sleep  2s
            Click Button     xpath=//input[@id='submit3']
            click element  xpath://html/body/div/div[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td/center/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/small/input

            Sleep  2s
            alert should be present

            #Click ok button
            click element   xpath=//form/input
            Sleep    25s
            
         ELSE IF    ${code} != 10
            sleep  2s
            Click Button     xpath=//input[@id='submit3']

            Alert Should Be Present       The value entered is incorrect: 'code'   DISMISS    1s
            sleep  20s
            click element  xpath://html/body/div/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/center/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/small/input

            Sleep  2s
            alert should be present
```

If I compile only one area (By commenting other three areas) it works fine. Otherwise, most of the time, it displays the error that I mentioned earlier. I want to compile the whole code within one attempt.

And also sometimes, the XPaths that worked previous days are not working now. So, I have to find those Xpaths so many times.

I searched about this matter to find the solution but I couldn’t do it.
So, I want to know the reasons for the above-mentioned problems and need your suggestions and solutions to solve those issues.

Comment: Hello, Please read [mcve] and [tour] and edit your post accordingly to receive and appropriate answers

Comment: You have a lot of sleeps in your code. It looks like the application is slow and sometimes the test is a little bit too fast. I recommend that you replace sleep keywords with `Wait Until Page Contains Element` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use relative xpaths and with selenium library keywords you can achieve dynamic wait.
Try below code, ensure all xpaths are correct and highlights in dev tool.
Also you can remove all hardcoded waits.

```
    ${sometimeout}=    set Variable   30
    click element  xpath://app-sidebar/div/ul/li[5]/a/p
    Wait Until Element Is Visible  ${LOCATOR_Card_Number}  ${sometimeout}
   
    input text   ${LOCATOR_Card_Number}     ${Card_Number}
    Sleep  1s
    input text   ${LOCATOR_code}    ${code}
    
    IF    ${Card_Number} != 111111
            sleep  2s
            Click Button     xpath=//input[@id='submit3']
            Wait Until Page Contains Element    ///table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td/center/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/small/input
            click element  xpath:///table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td/center/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/small/input

            Sleep  2s
            alert should be present

            #Click ok button
            click element   xpath=//form/input
            Sleep    25s
            
         ELSE IF    ${code} != 10
            sleep  2s
            Click Button     xpath=//input[@id='submit3']

            Alert Should Be Present       The value entered is incorrect: 'code'   DISMISS    1s
            Wait Until Page Contains Element    //table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/center/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/small/input    ${sometimeout}
            click element  xpath://table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/center/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/small/input

            Sleep  2s
            alert should be present
```

for further investigation you can go though the below mentioned link
https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Page%20Contains%20Element